# Reading URIs with spaces in Turtle using Jena?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to read RDF from a Turtle file (shown below), but I'm having two problems. First, is there a  problem with whitespace in RDF or Turtle? Somtimes, I have a problem reading URIs l ike `<I/O Performance>`.  The problem disappears when I remove the spaces, giving `<IOPerformance>`.   In the file below, I have this problem with `<Standard(M1) - Small(default)>`.  Here is my code for loading the file and listing the subject, predicate, and object of each triple.

```java
  StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
        Resource subject = stmt.getSubject(); // sujeito

        Property predicate = stmt.getPredicate(); // predicado

        RDFNode object = stmt.getObject(); // objeto

        System.out.println((subject.getLocalName());
        System.out.println((predicate.getLocalName().toString()); 

        System.out.println(StringUtils.substringBetween(object.toString(),"", "^"));

   }
```

```
@prefix dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix legal:   <http://www.linked-usdl.org/ns/usdl-legal#> .
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix vann:    <http://purl.org/vocab/vann/> .
@prefix org:     <http://www.w3.org/ns/org#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix price:   <http://www.linked-usdl.org/ns/usdl-price#> .
@prefix usdl:    <http://www.linked-usdl.org/ns/usdl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dei:     <http://dei.uc.pt/rdf/dei#> .
@prefix gr:      <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#> .
@prefix skos:    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .

<Standard(M1) - Small(default)>
      rdfs:CPU "1 EC2 Compute Unit"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:Cost "0.08"^^xsd:float ;
      rdfs:EBS-OptimizedAvailable
              "false"^^xsd:boolean ;
      rdfs:IOPerformance "Moderate"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:OS "Linux/UNIX"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:Platform "32-bit"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:RAM "1.7"^^xsd:float ;
      rdfs:Storage "160"^^xsd:float .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Standard(M1) - Small(default)>` is not a legal URI.

1. It has spaces in it.
2. It's a relative URI (relative to where the file is read from) which makes it hard to guess the full, absolute URI.

Either add `@base` or use a prefixed name.

Comment: ok, so white spaces aren't allowed, right?
I have a file xml which I used to create the file rdf > https://gist.github.com/I-am-Gabi/564acdc43d18d747c5e5  

How would be the URI to that service? I got a question at this point about URI.

Answer (score 2):

The original concept of URI References in RDF 1.0 supported white spaces. But the concept of URI References was only introduced because IRIs weren't introduced yet. IRIs replace URI References and do not support white spaces.

Comment: This is not true.  The specification for URI syntax for [RDF 1.0 ](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-primer-20040210/#ref-uri) is Appendix A of [RFC 2396](http://www.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc2396.txt), and it does not permit whitespace.  [As noted](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-concepts-20040210/#dfn-URI-reference), URIs in RDF are forward compatible with IRIs: "Note: RDF URI references are compatible with International Resource Identifiers as defined by [XML Namespaces 1.1].".

Comment: Are there some way to show the the data of file with space? I see that in case of whitespace, they need to be handled with percent encoding... but i don't know as write that in code.

Comment: What are the criterion to create a URI? 
Based on this RDF/XML file https://gist.github.com/I-am-Gabi/564acdc43d18d747c5e5, as would be the URI for the service Standard (M1) - Small (default)?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I am talking about URI References in RDF 1.0 as defined in the abstract syntax (http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-concepts-20040210/#section-Graph-URIref) not about URIs. URI References could have white spaces, URIs clearly cannot. There are URI References which are NOT valid IRIs, in such a case as noted "Implementations may issue warnings concerning the use of RDF URI References that do not conform with [IRI draft] or its successors."

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you're saying.  The URI reference is a Unicode string that could contain whitespace, but the URI that it represents would not have the whitespace, but rather the percent-encoding of the whitespace.  So it's not a matter of the URI references not supporting whitespace;  they **do**.  The problem is that the Turtle syntax isn't doing anything with a URI reference, but uses the content between `<` and `>` as URI characters where the space isn't permitted.

Comment: But with regard to "There are URI References which are NOT valid IRIs":  If I'm reading this correctly, **no** URI reference is a valid IRI.  A URI reference is a **unicode string**, whereas an IRI is an IRI.  However, a URI reference **designates** a URI, and every URI is a legal IRI.  So every URI reference still designates a legal IRI.  (If the way I'm understanding that is correct.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: In Turtle, what you have between `<` and `>` is a relative IRI (in the latest version). An IRI like an RDF URI Reference is a sequence of unicode characters that can be mapped to a URI (see Abstract of RFC 3987). As the characters permitted in URIs map to themselves, and URI considered as character string is an IRI and is also an RDF URI Reference. Note that in RDF two IRIs/URI References are equal only if they are equal character-by-character. Two IRIs mapping to the same URI but with different characters are not considered to be equal in RDF.

Comment: @GabrielaCavalcante if you really want to have white spaces you could encode them with %20: <Standard(M1)%20-%20Small(default)> (assuming a suitable base IRI).  But it looks more like a description that should be in an RDF Literal, e.g.:
`[] 
      dc:description "Standard(M1) - Small(default)";
      rdfs:CPU "1 EC2 Compute Unit"^^xsd:string ;`

Comment: can be that?
rdf:StandardM1-Large
      rdfs:CPU "4 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores with 2 EC2 Compute Units each)"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:Cost "0.32"^^xsd:float ;
      rdfs:EBS-OptimizedAvailable;